# Pandas melt 2 groups of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, normalization, melt

I have a table as

```
id   name  sec1   sec2   sec3  sec4  sec5  sec6
1    abc   mp(6)  up(7)  sp(8) cp(7)  2     4
```

and i want output as

```
id   name   tests  values   slots
1    abc     mp     6        2
1    abc     up     7        2
1    abc     sp     8        2
1    abc     cp     7        2
1    abc     mp     6        4
1    abc     up     7        4
1    abc     sp     8        4
1    abc     cp     7        4
```

Can someone help me with normalising this with melt.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what have you tried, what has failed?

Comment: I have tried melt with sec5 and sec6 columns but it has eliminated the sec1,sec2.sec3,sec4 columns

Answer (score 1):

First we start with `set_index` and `stack()`.

We then extract the test value and place it with its own column and reset the index:

```
s = df.set_index(['id','name'],append=True).stack().to_frame('tests')
s['values'] = s['tests'].str.extract('(\d+)')[0]
df1 = s.dropna(subset=['values']).reset_index([1,2,3])
df1['tests'] = df1['tests'].str.replace('\(.*\)','')
```

---

```
print(df1)
   id name level_3 tests values
0   1  abc    sec1    mp      6
0   1  abc    sec2    up      7
0   1  abc    sec3    sp      8
0   1  abc    sec4    cp      7
```

---

Okay, now we need to something very similar to a cross join in SQL, that is repeat the dataframe according the `len` of the slots and add each value accordingly.

Note, this is making a product of your dataframe, a better way would be to use merge but you've not made your input clear, as in how multiple rows will appear.

Let's try this with `pd.concat` making use of the `keys` argument:

```
vals = s.loc[s['values'].isna(),'tests'].values

final = pd.concat([df1 ]* len(vals),0,keys=vals)\
            .reset_index(0).rename(columns={'level_0' : 'slots'})
```

---

```
print(final[['id','name','tests','values','slots']])

   id name tests values  slots
0   1  abc    mp      6      2
0   1  abc    up      7      2
0   1  abc    sp      8      2
0   1  abc    cp      7      2
0   1  abc    mp      6      4
0   1  abc    up      7      4
0   1  abc    sp      8      4
0   1  abc    cp      7      4
```

---

Avoiding a total product using `merge`:

```
vals = s.loc[s['values'].isna(), 'tests'].reset_index([2,3],drop=True)\
                   .to_frame('slots').reset_index(1)


print(pd.merge(df1,vals,on=['id']))


   id name level_3 tests values slots
0   1  abc    sec1    mp      6     2
1   1  abc    sec1    mp      6     4
2   1  abc    sec2    up      7     2
3   1  abc    sec2    up      7     4
4   1  abc    sec3    sp      8     2
5   1  abc    sec3    sp      8     4
6   1  abc    sec4    cp      7     2
7   1  abc    sec4    cp      7     4
```

Comment: Nice answer its really tricky question to solve. Keep up the good work :)

Comment: Really interesting question! I thought its worth trying out..Here is one solution I came up with if you would like to check it out [here is the link](https://repl.it/@ShubhamSharma13/BlissfulGruesomeEvent#main.py). And thanks for for letting me know about this question :-)

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was tough or if I was misunderstanding the data structure, in SQL this would I think i could do this with fewer lines of code, but would struggle with regex extracts. nice solution :) @ShubhamSharma

Answer (score 0):

One way about it is to `melt` twice, then extract the text and numbers into separate columns:

```
(
    df.melt(["id", "name", "sec5", "sec6"], var_name="var1", value_name="tests")
      .melt(["id", "name", "var1", "tests"], value_name="slots")
      .assign(values=lambda df: df.tests.str.extract(r"(\d)"),
             tests=lambda df: df.tests.str.extract(r"([a-z]+)"))
      .loc[:, ["id", "name", "tests", "values", "slots"]]
)

   id name tests values  slots
0   1  abc    mp      6      2
1   1  abc    up      7      2
2   1  abc    sp      8      2
3   1  abc    cp      7      2
4   1  abc    mp      6      4
5   1  abc    up      7      4
6   1  abc    sp      8      4
7   1  abc    cp      7      4
```